# Create New Text File Named After a Cell When Meeting a Criteria

Tags: vba, excel, for-loop

I've looked and found a little help so far but I'm stuggling with the for each logic for this Excel Macro I'm trying to make.

Basically I have 4 columns of data.  Column A has the name of something and column D has either TRUE or FALSE.

I would like a macro wired to a button that creates a new text file in a given directory named after the content of Col A but only if Col D in that row is labled as "TRUE".

For example if I have the following.

ColA = Test  ColD = TRUE

ColA = Test2 ColD = FALSE

ColA = Test3 ColD = TRUE

I will get 2 text files anmed Test.txt and Test3.txt.

I know I need a for each loop to look through the range of a1-d(whatever number) and then when D = True do a SaveAs I guess??

This is the code I have so far (yes I know it's very incomplete but this is as far as my logic got before hitting a wall).

```
Dim fileName As String
Dim filePath As String
Dim curCell As Object
Dim hideRange As Range

filePath = "C:\ExcelTest\"
hideRange = Range("D1:D1048576")
fileName = *Content of Cell A from this Row*

For Each Row In Range("A1:D1048576")
    IF curCell.value In Range hideRange = "TRUE"
      Then curCell.SaveAs fileName & ".txt, xlTextWindows
```

Any help or even pointing me in the right direction would be great.  I searched around a bit for some examples and couldn't find anything that really matched what I wanted to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are pretty close, but you are looping one hell of a lot of cells there.

Here is the code to loop the rows, this stops at the last populated cell in the column.

```
Sub LoopRows()

dim sht as worksheet
set sht = Thisworkbook.Sheets("Name of Worksheet")

'loop from row 1 to the last row containing data
For i = 1 To sht.Range("A:A").End(xlDown).Row
    'check the value in column 4 for this row (i)
    If sht.Cells(i, 4).Text = "TRUE" Then
        CreateFile sht.Cells(i, 1).Value
    End If
Next i

End Sub
```

For writing the file, to keep it simple it would reference Microsoft scripting runtime and do it as follows:

```
Sub CreateFile(FileName As String)
    Dim fso As New FileSystemObject
    fso.CreateTextFile "c:\temp\" & FileName & ".txt", True
End Sub
```

**EDIT**
I can't see why you aren't getting a file created, my tests work fine for me on a windows machine.

Can you please try the following code alone in a button and see if it opens a text file?

```
Dim fso As New FileSystemObject
fso.CreateTextFile "c:\temp\testfso.txt"
Shell "C:\WINDOWS\notepad.exe c:\temp\testfso.txt", vbMaximizedFocus
```

**EDIT 2**

Try this, and see if it opens the text file..

```
Sub CreateFile(FileName As String)
    Dim fso As New FileSystemObject
    Dim fName as String
    fName = "c:\temp\" & FileName & ".txt"
    fso.CreateTextFile fName, True
    Shell "C:\WINDOWS\notepad.exe " & fName, vbMaximizedFocus
End Sub
```

Comment: are you joking me? my version goes through 4 cells in his example, yours iterates over 4 million for no reason.

Comment: @NickDewitt

I cant seem to find proper syntax to do a file creation through excel, I'm trying to use Open from this example [link](http://www.meadinkent.co.uk/XLexport-text2.htm ) but no file is created.



`Sub CreateFile(FileName As String)


Dim filePath As String


filePath = "C:\ExcelTest\"


    Open filePath & FileName & ".txt" For Output As #1


End Sub`

Comment: @NickDewitt Even after adding your case for the file creation It's still not creating any files.  And yes I changed the directory to the proper file path I'm looking in.

Does the fact that I have this macro'd to a button change anything?

Comment: You need to add a reference to Microsoft Scripting Runtime for this, go to tools --> properties.

Comment: @Dirk, I have been there, copied the example into excel 2013, run it and comp2 runs 1 second faster, if I specify a sheet, e.g Sheet1.Cells instead of just 'Cells' then it runs about 2 seconds faster. Have you actually tried it?

Comment: @NickDewitt I should have stated that I already added that reference, still no files.

Comment: @user - tested and it works fine for me, are you changing the location of `c:\temp`in your code? Are you running this on windows?

Comment: @NickDewitt yes I changed the location of c:\Temp.  This is what I'm running tied to a button.  

    `Sub Button4_Click()

    Dim fso As New FileSystemObject

    For i = 1 To Sheet1.Range("A:A").End(xlDown).Row

    If Sheet1.Cells(i, 4).Value = "TRUE" Then
        fso.CreateTextFile "C:\ExcelTest\" & Sheet1.Cells(i, 1).Value, True
    End If
    
    Next i

    End Sub`

Comment: Sorry for poor editing, apparently I can't figure out how to send a block of code through this terrible commenting system....

Comment: Comments are not very good for code, I have added a snippet for you to test at the bottom of my answer to see if a file is truly being created or not, can you try it for me please?

Comment: @NickDewitt Snippet works, other code still does not.  It has to be some way that I'm formatting the file name, that's the only things that different.  Does it not support the & sign for adding to the path?

Comment: Ok, I have updated the `CreateFile` function, I think it might be as simple as we aren't setting the file extension.

Comment: What does the function in EDIT 2 do for you? do you get any error messages? does it open notepad? if it does open notepad, is notepad showing a message saying the file does not exist?

Comment: can you step through the code with F8 for me please and say what happens then (click inside the LoopRows routine and keep pressing F8 until it ends)

Comment: You can see the output at the bottom, all it shows is i increasing by 1 each time for the 3 rows i currently have then goes to end sub [LINK](https://i.imgur.com/8yngjPE.jpg).

Comment: Well then the value in column 4 is not equal to `TRUE`, if it never gets to the `CreateFile` line..

Comment: So why is it not picking that value up??  The syntax and logic you gave me should be grabbing it.  [This is the actual sheet im testing on](https://i.imgur.com/Mm8tCjl.jpg).  The TRUE / FALSE statements are populated by the check boxes which are linked to the cell in column D for that row, is that breaking something?  I'm normally a jr sql dev and havent done any VB before and I hate this lol.

Comment: i changed the LoopRows function slightly - you need to put in the name of your worksheet where it says `"Name of Worksheet"`

Comment: It is on Sheet1.  Tried the new edit and when I step through it still doesn't show a value of True or False just the i increasing for the number of rows.

Comment: Try changing `="TRUE"` to `=True`

Comment: WE DID IT!!  Changing it to True worked, I didn't think about it seeing that field as boolean value instead of a string till you mentioned it.  Derp.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is something like this:

```
Sub test()
  Dim filePath As String
  filePath = "C:\ExcelTest\"

  Dim xRow As Variant
  For Each xRow In Range("A1:D100").Rows
    If xRow(1, 4).Value = "TRUE" Then

      Open filePath & xRow(1, 1) & ".txt" For Output As #1
      Write #1, xRow(1, 2), xRow(1, 3)
      Close #1

    End If
  Next
End Sub
```

While it works without errors, I would not use it as it is right now.
If you have any questions, just ask.

**EDIT**

I've run some tests and noticed windows prevents me to create files inside specific folders... pls try this as a new sub and run it:

```
Sub testForText()
  Open Environ("AppData") & "\Testing.txt" For Output As #1
  Write #1, "dada"
  Close #1
  Shell "notepad.exe " & Environ("AppData") & "\Testing.txt", vbNormalFocus
End Sub
```

Then tell me if notepad opens up with "Testing.txt"

Comment: So you are going to run this over 4,194,304 cells?

Comment: The logic here looks right, I edited the ranged to only go through D100 because it will never really be higher than that.  I get an application-defined object error now and am not sure why yet.

Comment: alright I will give you that I missed you had added a .Rows from his example but still it's bad practice to loop like that and why not just `.columns("A")` ? I don't think we are helping him understand where he was going wrong by repeating that bit.

Comment: I am not iterating each cell, I am counting the cells and iterating an integer of 1 to 4. read my code.

Comment: @user2362927 pls try if this works (in direct window): `Open "C:\ExcelTest\test0815.txt" For Output As #1` and then check if the file is there...

Comment: See my comment above, it's not slow, I tested your example over 1m iterations and mine was faster.

Comment: @user2362927 does the code in my comment above not create anything? It is confusing cus no error pops up...

Comment: I agree with @Dirk, both of our code should work and create a file (we are only really arguing over performance issues and simplification) - something is amiss here especially as you are getting no errors and the test you did with the EDIT 1 code worked..

Comment: @user2362927 pls run `Shell "explorer.exe C:\ExcelTest\", vbNormalFocus` in direct window and check for the files (just to get that out of my mind)... pls don't get me/that wrong...

Comment: @DirkReichel Ran and the directory opens in file explorer.  No files exist.

Comment: @DirkReichel Opens notepad with nothing in the document which is what I assume is supposed to happen.

Comment: @user2362927 it should be empty, yes... but the title sould state "Testing.txt"... looks like we got your problem ;) edited it again... now there should be text inside...

Comment: @DirkReichel If i run just what you have in your original post i still get the run-time error, that's why iv'e been following up more with the other option given that Nick's runs with no error even though the files aren't present.

Comment: @DirkReichel same run-time error 1004.  Application-defined or object-defined error....

Comment: @user2362927 pls do me a favor... knowing there is also more code in this workbook, close excel completely. open up excel and make a new file. open up the vba window and input my `testForText`-code and then run it... sorry for bothering you to do it over and over...

Comment: while doing that notheing else in excel should be open

Comment: @DirkReichel testForText runs correctly.  This doesnt solve the problem that your actual solution does not work in the sheet where it actually needs to run..

Comment: @user2362927 the reason for not working is the other code you have in the workbook... like declaring a variable name which is not allowed... `Dim Range as Variant` can confuse excel completely... you need to check for everything which could cause this... sorry, may be a lot of work for you now... mostly all variable, sub and function names